# Visual Studio C++ exceptions not catched

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, exception

Using VS2013, in the C++ code below I get a debug assertion when accessing the vector with an out of range index, which is OK (but the catch block is not reached). When running the release version the program runs without the exception being caught. The output is 1 while it should be 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

vector<int> Vector;

void GetException()
try{
    int Sum{ 0 };
    // Access an element beyond the end of the vector
    for( int i = 0; i <= Vector.size(); i++ )
        Sum += Vector[i];
}
catch( ... ){
    Vector.clear();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Vector.push_back( 1 );
    GetException();

    cout << Vector.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I change it to access a nullptr I get in the debug version an error message for an "unhandled exception" and in the release version it crashes on the access. Are there parameters in VS that modify the behaviour of exceptions?

```
int Sum{ 0 };

void GetException()
try{
    int *pSum{ nullptr };
    Sum = *pSum;
}
catch( ... ){
    Sum = 1;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    GetException();

    cout << Sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are getting this diagnostic from the iterator debugging feature.  It does not use an exception to tell you that you did it wrong, catching an exception never once fixed a bug.  You must fix your code instead.

Comment: Head over to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector and read on operator [], and then on at(). You'll find out you want to use at() if you want exceptions to be thrown when element indices are out of range.

Comment: @Hans: Of course bugs must be fixed but catching exceptions allows to show the user a decent error message that can help the developper to find the bug and then the user can continue to work (well most of it that is). A program crash helps no one...

Comment: That does not make much sense, your user will never see this because you'll deploy the optimized release build, the one that does *not* have the iterator debugging feature enabled.  Rather important, it makes code quite slow.  The feature is only for *your* benefit and only intended to fix bugs.

Answer (score 2):

This expression `Vector[i]` (in your first code example) does not throw exceptions (in normal, release builds anyways), it's simply undefined behavior if `i` is out of bounds.

This expression `Vector.at(i)` does throw exceptions (in normal, release builds) if `i` is out of bounds.

If you want to have a `std::vector` do bounds checking for you, and throw exceptions if an access is out of bounds, then you should use that form. You can't `catch` the problem if a `Vector[i]` access is out of bounds.